# Blas++ cannot find OpenBLAS in CMake on Windows

Tags: c++, cmake, openblas

I am trying to use [BLAS++](https://icl.bitbucket.io/blaspp/) with OpenBLAS. Everything works fine on Linux but now I want to make my lib a bit more cross-platform.

I have this minimal CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(test)

find_package(Git REQUIRED)

function(update_git_submodule dir)
  execute_process(
    COMMAND ${GIT_EXECUTABLE} submodule update --init --recursive -- ${dir}
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
    RESULT_VARIABLE GIT_SUBMOD_RESULT)
  if(NOT GIT_SUBMOD_RESULT EQUAL "0")
    message(FATAL_ERROR "When updating submodule ${dir}")
  endif()
endfunction()

set(BLASPP_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/external/blaspp)
update_git_submodule(${BLASPP_DIR})
add_subdirectory(${BLASPP_DIR})
```

BLAS++ is a git submodule. It clones successfully and CMake than lets BLAS++ search for any BLAS implementation. However the problem is that it does not find OpenBLAS:

```
BLAS++ requires a BLAS library and none was found.  Ensure that it is accessible in environment variables $CPATH, $LIBRARY_PATH, and $LD_LIBRARY_PATH.
```

I tried setting all variables to the `share\cmake` folder in powershell and also as CMake variables, nothing worked. Also when specifying `BLA_VENDOR` in CMake it will not find OpenBLAS.

Here comes what I did with OpenBLAS:
I cloned the [repo from github](https://github.com/xianyi/OpenBLAS) (outside of the actual project), built it and installed it. Now I have the build directory of CMake with the compiled OpenBLAS files and the files in C:\Program Files(x86). In the latter there is a folder `share\cmake` with all the CMake scripts including `OpenBLASConfig.cmake` to be able to find OpenBLAS.
CMake now has to find those scripts but as it seems it doesn't.

The question is actually how do I tell CMake globally to search in `C:\Program Files(x86)\OpenBLAS\share\cmake`?

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

`--debug-find` prints the following:

```
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:4 (find_package)


-- Found Git: C:/Program Files/Git/cmd/git.exe (found version "2.36.1.windows.1")
CMake Debug Log at CMakeLists.txt:4 (find_package):
  find_package considered the following paths for FindGit.cmake:

  The file was found at

    C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/FindGit.cmake



-- Using CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX = C:/Program Files (x86)/test
CMake Error at external/blaspp/CMakeLists.txt:97 (set_property):
  set_property could not find CACHE variable CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE.  Perhaps it
  has not yet been created.


-- Looking for a CUDA compiler
-- Looking for a CUDA compiler - NOTFOUND
-- Not building CUDA support in BLAS++
-- Looking for HIP/ROCm
CMake Debug Log at external/blaspp/CMakeLists.txt:293 (find_package):
  find_package considered the following paths for Findrocblas.cmake:

    C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/Findrocblas.cmake

  The file was not found.

  <PackageName>_ROOT CMake variable [CMAKE_FIND_USE_PACKAGE_ROOT_PATH].

    none

  CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH variable [CMAKE_FIND_USE_CMAKE_PATH].

    none

  CMAKE_FRAMEWORK_PATH and CMAKE_APPBUNDLE_PATH variables
  [CMAKE_FIND_USE_CMAKE_PATH].

    none

  Env variable rocblas_DIR [CMAKE_FIND_USE_CMAKE_ENVIRONMENT_PATH].

    none

  CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH env variable [CMAKE_FIND_USE_CMAKE_ENVIRONMENT_PATH].

    none

  CMAKE_FRAMEWORK_PATH and CMAKE_APPBUNDLE_PATH env variables
  [CMAKE_FIND_USE_CMAKE_ENVIRONMENT_PATH].

    none

  Paths specified by the find_package HINTS option.

    none

  Standard system environment variables
  [CMAKE_FIND_USE_SYSTEM_ENVIRONMENT_PATH].

    C:/Program Files/PowerShell/7
    C:/Windows/System32
    C:/Windows
    C:/Windows/System32/wbem
    C:/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0
    C:/Windows/System32/OpenSSH
    C:/Program Files (x86)/NVIDIA Corporation/PhysX/Common
    C:/Program Files/NVIDIA Corporation/NVIDIA NvDLISR
    C:/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/150/Tools/Binn
    C:/Program Files/Git/cmd
    C:/Program Files/dotnet
    C:/Program Files/gs/gs9.56.1
    C:/Program Files (x86)/TeX2img
    C:/Program Files/Neovim
    C:/Program Files/treesitter
    C:/Program Files/ImageMagick-7.1.0-Q16-HDRI
    C:/Program Files/LLVM
    C:/texlive/2022/bin/win32
    C:/Program Files/CMake
    C:/Program Files/fzf
    C:/Program Files (x86)/pkg-config
    C:/Program Files (x86)/glib
    C:/Program Files (x86)/gettext-runtime
    C:/Users/steve/miniconda3
    C:/Users/steve/miniconda3/Library/mingw-w64
    C:/Users/steve/miniconda3/Library/usr
    C:/Users/steve/miniconda3/Library
    C:/Users/steve/miniconda3/Scripts
    C:/Users/steve/scoop/shims
    C:/Users/steve/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps
    C:/Users/steve/.dotnet/tools

  CMake User Package Registry [CMAKE_FIND_USE_PACKAGE_REGISTRY].

    none

  CMake variables defined in the Platform file
  [CMAKE_FIND_USE_CMAKE_SYSTEM_PATH].

    C:/Program Files
    C:/Program Files (x86)
    C:/Program Files (x86)/test

  CMake System Package Registry
  [CMAKE_FIND_PACKAGE_NO_SYSTEM_PACKAGE_REGISTRY].

    none

  Paths specified by the find_package PATHS option.

    none

  find_package considered the following locations for rocblas's Config
  module:

    C:/Program Files/PowerShell/7/rocblasConfig.cmake
    C:/Program Files/PowerShell/7/rocblas-config.cmake
    C:/Windows/System32/rocblasConfig.cmake
    C:/Windows/System32/rocblas-config.cmake
    C:/Windows/rocblasConfig.cmake
    C:/Windows/rocblas-config.cmake
    C:/Windows/System32/wbem/rocblasConfig.cmake
    C:/Windows/System32/wbem/rocblas-config.cmake
    C:/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/rocblasConfig.cmake
    C:/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/rocblas-config.cmake
    C:/Windows/System32/OpenSSH/rocblasConfig.cmake
    C:/Windows/System32/OpenSSH/rocblas-config.cmake
    C:/Program Files (x86)/NVIDIA Corporation/PhysX/Common/rocblasConfig.cmake
    C:/Program Files (x86)/NVIDIA Corporation/PhysX/Common/rocblas-config.cmake
    C:/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/150/Tools/Binn/rocblasConfig.cmake
    C:/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/150/Tools/Binn/rocblas-config.cmake
    C:/Program Files/Git/cmd/rocblasConfig.cmake
    C:/Program Files/Git/cmd/rocblas-config.cmake
    C:/Program Files/dotnet/rocblasConfig.cmake
    C:/Program Files/dotnet/rocblas-config.cmake
    C:/Program Files/gs/gs9.56.1/rocblasConfig.cmake
    C:/Program Files/gs/gs9.56.1/rocblas-config.cmake
    C:/Program Files (x86)/TeX2img/rocblasConfig.cmake
    C:/Program Files (x86)/TeX2img/rocblas-config.cmake
    C:/Program Files/Neovim/rocblasConfig.cmake
    C:/Program Files/Neovim/rocblas-config.cmake
    C:/Program Files/treesitter/rocblasConfig.cmake
    C:/Program Files/treesitter/rocblas-config.cmake
    C:/Program Files/ImageMagick-7.1.0-Q16-HDRI/rocblasConfig.cmake
    C:/Program Files/ImageMagick-7.1.0-Q16-HDRI/rocblas-config.cmake
    C:/Program Files/LLVM/rocblasConfig.cmake
    C:/Program Files/LLVM/rocblas-config.cmake
    C:/texlive/2022/bin/win32/rocblasConfig.cmake
    C:/texlive/2022/bin/win32/rocblas-config.cmake
    C:/Program Files/CMake/rocblasConfig.cmake
    C:/Program Files/CMake/rocblas-config.cmake
    C:/Program Files/fzf/rocblasConfig.cmake
    C:/Program Files/fzf/rocblas-config.cmake
    C:/Program Files (x86)/pkg-config/rocblasConfig.cmake
    C:/Program Files (x86)/pkg-config/rocblas-config.cmake
    C:/Program Files (x86)/glib/rocblasConfig.cmake
    C:/Program Files (x86)/glib/rocblas-config.cmake
    C:/Program Files (x86)/gettext-runtime/rocblasConfig.cmake
    C:/Program Files (x86)/gettext-runtime/rocblas-config.cmake
    C:/Users/steve/miniconda3/rocblasConfig.cmake
    C:/Users/steve/miniconda3/rocblas-config.cmake
    C:/Users/steve/miniconda3/Library/rocblasConfig.cmake
    C:/Users/steve/miniconda3/Library/rocblas-config.cmake
    C:/Users/steve/miniconda3/Library/cmake/rocblasConfig.cmake
    C:/Users/steve/miniconda3/Library/cmake/rocblas-config.cmake
    C:/Users/steve/miniconda3/Scripts/rocblasConfig.cmake
    C:/Users/steve/miniconda3/Scripts/rocblas-config.cmake
    C:/Users/steve/scoop/shims/rocblasConfig.cmake
    C:/Users/steve/scoop/shims/rocblas-config.cmake
    C:/Users/steve/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/rocblasConfig.cmake
    C:/Users/steve/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/rocblas-config.cmake
    C:/Program Files/rocblasConfig.cmake
    C:/Program Files/rocblas-config.cmake
    C:/Program Files/CMake/rocblasConfig.cmake
    C:/Program Files/CMake/rocblas-config.cmake
    C:/Program Files (x86)/rocblasConfig.cmake
    C:/Program Files (x86)/rocblas-config.cmake

  The file was not found.



-- Not building HIP/ROCm support in BLAS++
-- Found OpenMP_C: -openmp (found version "2.0")
-- Found OpenMP_CXX: -openmp (found version "2.0")
-- Found OpenMP: TRUE (found version "2.0")
CMake Debug Log at external/blaspp/CMakeLists.txt:329 (find_package):
  find_package considered the following paths for FindOpenMP.cmake:

  The file was found at

    C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/FindOpenMP.cmake



-- blaspp_id = ab91e06
-- Looking for BLAS libraries and options
Skipping threaded MKL for non-GNU, non-Intel compiler with OpenMP
←[1mdefault (no library)←[22m
   libs:
   -DBLAS_FORTRAN_ADD_                             ←[31m no (didn't link: routine not found)←[39m
   -DBLAS_FORTRAN_LOWER                            ←[31m no (didn't link: routine not found)←[39m
   -DBLAS_FORTRAN_UPPER                            ←[31m no (didn't link: routine not found)←[39m

←[1mIntel MKL lp64,  sequential, gfortran←[22m
   libs:  -lmkl_gf_lp64  -lmkl_sequential -lmkl_core
   -DBLAS_FORTRAN_ADD_                             ←[31m no (didn't link: routine not found)←[39m
   -DBLAS_FORTRAN_LOWER                            ←[31m no (didn't link: routine not found)←[39m
   -DBLAS_FORTRAN_UPPER                            ←[31m no (didn't link: routine not found)←[39m

←[1mIntel MKL ilp64, sequential, gfortran←[22m
   libs:  -lmkl_gf_ilp64 -lmkl_sequential -lmkl_core
   -DBLAS_FORTRAN_ADD_                             ←[31m no (didn't link: routine not found)←[39m
   -DBLAS_FORTRAN_LOWER                            ←[31m no (didn't link: routine not found)←[39m
   -DBLAS_FORTRAN_UPPER                            ←[31m no (didn't link: routine not found)←[39m

←[1mIntel MKL lp64,  sequential, ifort←[22m
   libs:  -lmkl_intel_lp64  -lmkl_sequential -lmkl_core
   -DBLAS_FORTRAN_ADD_                             ←[31m no (didn't link: routine not found)←[39m
   -DBLAS_FORTRAN_LOWER                            ←[31m no (didn't link: routine not found)←[39m
   -DBLAS_FORTRAN_UPPER                            ←[31m no (didn't link: routine not found)←[39m

←[1mIntel MKL ilp64, sequential, ifort←[22m
   libs:  -lmkl_intel_ilp64 -lmkl_sequential -lmkl_core
   -DBLAS_FORTRAN_ADD_                             ←[31m no (didn't link: routine not found)←[39m
   -DBLAS_FORTRAN_LOWER                            ←[31m no (didn't link: routine not found)←[39m
   -DBLAS_FORTRAN_UPPER                            ←[31m no (didn't link: routine not found)←[39m

←[1mIBM ESSL int (lp64), multi-threaded, with OpenMP←[22m
   libs:  -lesslsmp
   -DBLAS_FORTRAN_ADD_                             ←[31m no (didn't link: routine not found)←[39m
   -DBLAS_FORTRAN_LOWER                            ←[31m no (didn't link: routine not found)←[39m
   -DBLAS_FORTRAN_UPPER                            ←[31m no (didn't link: routine not found)←[39m

←[1mIBM ESSL int64 (ilp64), multi-threaded, with OpenMP←[22m
   libs:  -lesslsmp6464
   -DBLAS_FORTRAN_ADD_                             ←[31m no (didn't link: routine not found)←[39m
   -DBLAS_FORTRAN_LOWER                            ←[31m no (didn't link: routine not found)←[39m
   -DBLAS_FORTRAN_UPPER                            ←[31m no (didn't link: routine not found)←[39m

←[1mIBM ESSL int (lp64), sequential←[22m
   libs:  -lessl
   -DBLAS_FORTRAN_ADD_                             ←[31m no (didn't link: routine not found)←[39m
   -DBLAS_FORTRAN_LOWER                            ←[31m no (didn't link: routine not found)←[39m
   -DBLAS_FORTRAN_UPPER                            ←[31m no (didn't link: routine not found)←[39m

←[1mIBM ESSL int64 (ilp64), sequential←[22m
   libs:  -lessl6464
   -DBLAS_FORTRAN_ADD_                             ←[31m no (didn't link: routine not found)←[39m
   -DBLAS_FORTRAN_LOWER                            ←[31m no (didn't link: routine not found)←[39m
   -DBLAS_FORTRAN_UPPER                            ←[31m no (didn't link: routine not found)←[39m

←[1mOpenBLAS←[22m
   libs:  -lopenblas
   -DBLAS_FORTRAN_ADD_                             ←[31m no (didn't link: routine not found)←[39m
   -DBLAS_FORTRAN_LOWER                            ←[31m no (didn't link: routine not found)←[39m
   -DBLAS_FORTRAN_UPPER                            ←[31m no (didn't link: routine not found)←[39m

←[1mApple Accelerate←[22m
   libs:  -framework Accelerate
   -DBLAS_FORTRAN_ADD_                             ←[31m no (didn't link: routine not found)←[39m
   -DBLAS_FORTRAN_LOWER                            ←[31m no (didn't link: routine not found)←[39m
   -DBLAS_FORTRAN_UPPER                            ←[31m no (didn't link: routine not found)←[39m

←[1mgeneric←[22m
   libs:  -lblas
   -DBLAS_FORTRAN_ADD_                             ←[31m no (didn't link: routine not found)←[39m
   -DBLAS_FORTRAN_LOWER                            ←[31m no (didn't link: routine not found)←[39m
   -DBLAS_FORTRAN_UPPER                            ←[31m no (didn't link: routine not found)←[39m

←[1mAMD ACML threaded←[22m
   libs:  -lacml_mp
   -DBLAS_FORTRAN_ADD_                             ←[31m no (didn't link: routine not found)←[39m
   -DBLAS_FORTRAN_LOWER                            ←[31m no (didn't link: routine not found)←[39m
   -DBLAS_FORTRAN_UPPER                            ←[31m no (didn't link: routine not found)←[39m

←[1mAMD ACML sequential←[22m
   libs:  -lacml
   -DBLAS_FORTRAN_ADD_                             ←[31m no (didn't link: routine not found)←[39m
   -DBLAS_FORTRAN_LOWER                            ←[31m no (didn't link: routine not found)←[39m
   -DBLAS_FORTRAN_UPPER                            ←[31m no (didn't link: routine not found)←[39m

←[31m   BLAS library not found.←[39m
CMake Error at external/blaspp/CMakeLists.txt:374 (message):
  BLAS++ requires a BLAS library and none was found.  Ensure that it is
  accessible in environment variables $CPATH, $LIBRARY_PATH, and
  $LD_LIBRARY_PATH.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `C:\Program Files(x86)` to `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`? But this might be CMake stopping you from shooting yourself in the foot... if you're trying to build for 64-bit Windows, it won't search the `(x86)` folder. Did you build OpenBLAS as a 64-bit or 32-bit library?

Comment: You can also run with `--debug-find` to see why `find_package` failed.

Comment: In the build directory i ran `cmake .. -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH='C:\Program Files (x86)'` with no success.

Comment: TBH I do not know if it compiled to 64-bit or 32. I just let CMake decide by running `cmake --build . --config Release --target install` in the OpenBLAS build directory. I guess it compiled to 32-bit since it installed into the x86 folder.

Comment: Have you tried with the lastest CMake version? It got some improvements in the FindBlas code, but I don't remember whether that would affect you and your problem at hand.

Comment: I am currently on `3.23.2` which is rather up to date i guess.

Answer (score 2):

BLAS++ isn't looking for a BLAS library in a CMake package, it's just looking for a library that it can link to, e.g., on Unix something like `-lblas` which would match `libblas.so` or `libblas.a` in the compiler's library search path.

You could hard-code the whole path when calling CMake, something like

```
cmake -DBLAS_LIBRARIES=/path/to/openblas/lib/libopenblas.so ..
```

I'm not familiar with how to specify that in CMake on Windows.

BTW, you can get rid of the `←[31m` ANSI color codes by setting `color=no`.